# confirmation Email and how to access and alter user's profile fields?

Tags: python, django

I am  following a tutorial and everything is working fine, except being able to access the user's profile fields , and so far i am able to set the 'is_active' flag on User model, put 'user.profile.email_confirmed' is really not changing at all,so any Idea about what is that i am doing wrong.

## models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # relations
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

## tokens.py

```
class AccountActivationTokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
        return (
            six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp) +
            six.text_type(user.profile.email_confirmed)
        )


account_activation_token = AccountActivationTokenGenerator()
```

## urls.py

```
url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]
                                     {1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
                                 views.activate, name='activate'),
```

## views.py

```
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.profile.email_confirmed = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        return render(request, 'account_activation_invalid.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inserting

```
user.profile.save()
```

before your

```
user.save()
```

call.

It may help to view things from the underlying DBs perspective. Usually relations are stored as integers representing foreign keys to an entry in another database table.

Thus when you execute

```
user.save()
```

you are writing to the DB that `is_active` is now set to True but the user profile is still the same integer value as before, as you didn't change the profile object that the user has. As far as I know, Django doesn't go out of its way to figure out that the profile object has also been changed.

Comment: You were right Sir, now "user.profile.email_confirmed" is set to True,